# How to convert an 'int' data type item to 'string' and search in a string list using 'Contains' in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am working on a project which uses ASP.net web forms and C# entity framework using LINQ.
I am retrieving an 'int' type data list from one function and Check it in another string list using 'Contains'.
There I have used

> 'SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)MY_INT_ITEM).Trim()'

to convert that int type item (ID) to the string.
It worked before but now I forget how I did it. Now when I am trying to do that it gives the following error,

---

> *"Unable to cast the type 'System. Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive
>   or enumeration types."*

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix that? Here I have attached my code.
Thank you.

```
public static List<SESAssignmentsType> getNotUplodedUnitDetailsList(List<string> possibleUnits)
    {
        using (SESEntities db = new SESEntities())
        {
            var properUnitList = (from s in db.SES_SCHEDULE_LECTURE
                                  join u in db.SES_UNDERGRADUATE_UNIT_DETAILS on s.SCH_UNIT_ID equals u.ID
                                  where possibleUnits.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.ID).Trim())
                                  select new SESAssignmentsType
                                  {
                                      ID = s.ID,
                                      UNIT_NAME = u.UND_UNIT_NAME + " - " + a.SCH_START_DATE + " - " + a.SCH_START_TIME+ " ( Started " +
                                              SqlFunctions.DateName("day", a.SCH_START_DATE) + "/" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)a.SCH_START_DATE.Value.Month).TrimStart() + "/" + SqlFunctions.DateName("year", a.SCH_START_DATE)


                                  }).ToList();


            return properUnitList;
        }
    }
```

---

Thank you very much for your help. Finally, I found the issue it is because some of the values concatenated in UNIT_NAME is nullable.
@Rahul Sharma thank you very much for your idea to check nullable.

Comment: Please try to convert like this as `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double? value, int length, int decimals)` example given as `SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?) s.ID, 10, 2)`

Comment: @HardikMasalawala Thank you for the response. I tried now, but it doesn't work and is getting the same error.

Comment: You could check for your `nullable` type like this: `double? s.ID= string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.ID) ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(s.ID);`

Comment: @RahulSharma thank you for the response. It doesn't work. Cannot check nullable inside 'SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?) s.ID'.

Comment: Well, `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double?)` returns an integer converted to string. To return a decimal value, you need to provide the other overload `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double? value, int length, int decimals)` as mentioned by Hardik. For example: `SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?) "47.55", 20, 5) //Here result will be "47.55000"`. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Objects_SqlClient_SqlFunctions_StringConvert_System_Nullable_System_Double__

Comment: @NawodaDharmabandu where s.Id.HasValue && possibleUnits.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.Id).Trim())

Answer (score 0):

Check this after convert S.ID in to string in contains use like this below example
possibleUnits.Contains(s.ID.ToString())

Answer (score 0):

It looks for me that s.ID is a nullable, which means you should change it to this:

```
where possibleUnits.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.ID.Value).Trim())
```

Note that this doesnt check if s.ID is null, so you need to do that by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already tried but it doesn't work.